# Where can I get high quality vector graphics for web design?

Tags: web-development, website-design, images, graphics

I am looking for a place where I can buy web 2.0 (cartooney mac-like) vector graphics for use on my sites.

Where's the best place to go?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to really buy them, I recommend searching for online stock vectors shops, like:

- [www.myvectorstore.com](http://www.myvectorstore.com)
- [www.istockphoto.com](http://www.istockphoto.com)
- [www.shutterstock.com](http://www.shutterstock.com)
- [vectorstock.com](http://vectorstock.com)
- [www.stockillustrations.com](http://www.stockillustrations.com)
- [veer.com](http://veer.com)
- [www.stockillustration.com](http://www.stockillustration.com)
- [www.stockart.com](http://www.stockart.com)